# Wildcards in filepaths?

Tags: powershell

I've written a script that, when run by the user, will modify a document saved on a shared drive. What I'd like to happen once they've modified the document is to have the script save a copy to their desktop. I've tried a few variations of the following with no success:

```
Out-File C:\Users\[a-z , 0-9]*\Desktop\filecopy.txt
```

When run, it gives the error

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'FilePath.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the user in question will be the one executing the script?

If so, just use the `$env` built-in variable

```
out-file $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\filecopy.txt
```

Comment: No problem, make sure you poke around a bit in the `$env` variable, lots of useful things in there.

Comment: Using this approach can get tricky if the desktop is redirected to different location as where the userprofile (ntuser.dat) resides which is a common scenario in coorporate environments. A much better approach is using [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

Comment: Thanks for responding, Bluuf, but I'm not sure how I would implement your method. Would it look something like "Out-File [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')\$filecopy.txt" ?